# Recompile a JAR which is compiled with a very old version of JDK

Tags: java, jvm

I have a JAR which is probably compiled by a very old version of JDK. It requires Microsoft JVM to execute the JAR. If I want to recompile this JAR, which JDK version should I download and use? Are there any special issues I have to consider?

P.S. I am new to JAVA, please forgive my poor presentation.

Comment: I'd say try with the latest JDK. If there are issues, you'll run into them when you try to recompile it.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the said jar?

Comment: I'm quite sure there is no such thing as a Java JDK from MS. Do you mean JDK *for* Windows?

Comment: you should have the source code to recompile.

Comment: A jar is like a zip file. You should be able to extract it with WinZip, 7Zip, WinRar, ...
After you got all your *.class files, you can jar them again with your current JDK version

Comment: There was a Microsoft JVM which is now discontinued - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Java_Virtual_Machine

Comment: @drorb: That's creepy.

Comment: @DirkLachowski It certainly was.

Comment: sounds pretty impossible without the source code..

Comment: The source code was lost...

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very surprised if a JAR requires a specific JVM to run on. Java's whole philosophy is [write once run anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere).

If you don't already have the source, you can use a Java Decompiler (such as [jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29)) to decompile the .class files to .java files and then recompile using a modern JDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code, you should be able to compile it with the latest JDK. You might need to specify the source version (1.3, 1.4, ... ,1.7) if the code contains variable names which became reserved words in later versions of Java (assert, enum etc.). You can do it by using the `-source` option of the compiler.
If the jar was originally built by [Visual J++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950413.aspx) (you mentioned the Microsoft JVM), than I'm not sure if you can compile it with an Oracle JDK, really depends on what was used in the code.
If you do not have the source code, try using a Java decompiler such as [JAD](http://varaneckas.com/jad/) or [JD](http://jd.benow.ca/) to get the source code from the class files inside the jar. You need to verify that the decompiler supports bytecode created by older versions of Java.
You can find out for which target Java version the class were compiled using the methods described [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/how-to-find-java-the-compiler-target-version-from-a-java-class-file/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the method you mentioned to find out the Java version (which is possibly JDK 1.1.X), so I installed JDK 1.1.8 as the JAVA project reference (I already decompiled the JAR with JAD). However, there are plenty of errors exist (2XXX errors). What else can I do except from solving the errors one by one?

Comment: What types of errors? your source might be depending on 3rd party libraries, so you will get many missing import errors. If this is the case, you can try checking the jar manifest file and see if it contains references to the 3rd party jars. If the source was originally built with Microsoft Visual J++, than you are probably missing specific Microsoft dependencies which are not part of the Oracle (Sun) JDK.

Comment: Another interesting source of information which may help is the [MSJVM Transition Guide–IT Pro Version](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/7/f/a7f0d96d-c40a-4ce7-863a-139f5af69305/msjvm_itpro.pdf) which explains how to migrate Java application which were developed for the Microsoft JVM. I found the link to this guide in the [Microsoft Java Virtual Machine Support](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/interoperability/java/default.aspx) page

Answer (score 1):

JVM has a backward compatibility. So code written for java 1.4, for example, should run on the 8th JVM as well. The problem could be that your jar is using Microsoft JVM native classes, which are not part of the standard API. In this case you cant run it on any other JVM, the only way is to find sources and modify them to avoid vendor specific classes. This is the same as using SUN's API. By the way, how did you find out, that your jar requires Microsoft JVM?

Comment: I am informed that this JAR needs to install Microsoft JVM to use.

Comment: As I understood you want to modify logic. Without sources you cant do anything. The only possibility is to use byte code editors. But this could help only in very simple cases.